# MYSQL Query - Use format but no commas

Tags: mysql, format, number-formatting

I am trying to use format within an SQL query to suit a reporting package.  I have numbers that I need to show as currency with two decimal places so I am using the format command to do that.   The problem is that format also puts in a comma to separate thousands and the reporting package sum function cannot handle this so treats the formatted numeric value as text and does not add it in.   The query uses:-

```
SELECT customers.name AS "customers name", FORMAT(contracts.charge,2) AS "contracts charge" 
FROM customers
ORDER BY customers.name
```

(the actual query is a lot more complex but this is the relevant part)

To explain more fully:-

If the numeric value is 123.1 the formatted output is 123.10 which works.
If the numeric value is 1234.1 the formatted output is 1,234.10 which does not

I need to find a way to persuade the query to output 1234.10

Many thanks

Answer (score 21):

You could just:

```
REPLACE(FORMAT(contracts.charge, 2), ',', '')
```

Answer (score 16):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368280/mysql-format-number-output-thousands-separator) seems to have a much cleaner solution:

> Just use `ROUND`, this is a numeric function. `FORMAT` is a string function

Comment: As commented in the referenced answer, `round()` doesn’t add decimal digits. This doesn’t work as requested.

Answer (score 4):

A possible workaround would be replacing the comma after the format :

```
REPLACE(FORMAT(contracts.charge,2),',','') AS "contracts charge"
```

Answer (score -2):

Invertir , to decimal . to miles
REPLACE( REPLACE(REPLACE(FORMAT(contracts.charge,2),',','-') ,'.',',') ,'-','.') AS  contracts_charge

Comment: Really they should be setting their locale properly, not trying to do string replacement on the existing formatting like this.