# mySQL format number output , thousands separator

Tags: mysql, format, decimal

I have a mySQL query which is outputting decimal fields with a comma.

```
SELECT Metals.Metal, FORMAT(Fixes.GBPam, 3) AS AM, FORMAT(Fixes.GBPpm, 3) AS PM,     
DATE_FORMAT(Fixes.DateTime, '%d-%m-%y') AS Date
FROM Fixes, Metals
WHERE Metals.Id = Fixes.Metals_Id
```

Fields GBPam and GBPpm are both of type `decimal(10,5)`

Now I want columns AM and PM to be formatted to 3 decimal places in my sql query - Correct

I want values in the thousands to be formatted as xxxx.xxx and not x,xxx.xxx - Incorrect

Example output from mysql query:

```
Metal       AM          PM          Date
Gold        1,081.334   NULL    11-09-12
Silver      21.009      NULL    10-09-12
Platinum    995.650     NULL    11-09-12
Palladium   416.700     NULL    11-09-12
```

Can you see that output for Gold AM is 1,081.334? How can I get it to output 1081.334?

This is a pain in the ass for me because I have to then muck about in PHP to remove the comma. I would prefer to just get mysql to format it correctly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use `ROUND`, this is a numeric function. `FORMAT` is a string function

```
ROUND(Fixes.GBPam, 3)
```

Comment: Round doesn't add decimal if ORIGINAL number does not have decimal

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`replace`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) command for this purpose.

```
 REPLACE(Fixes.GBPam,',','')
```

**EDIT:**
With respect to your question you could do something like this:

```
SELECT Metals.Metal, ROUND(REPLACE(Fixes.GBPam,',',''),3) AS AM,
  ROUND(REPLACE(Fixes.GBPpm,',',''),3) AS PM,     
  DATE_FORMAT(Fixes.DateTime, '%d-%m-%y') AS Date
  FROM Fixes, Metals
WHERE Metals.Id = Fixes.Metals_Id
```

Comment: Does ROUND round up? e.g. what will round do to 1024.7854? Will I get back 1024.785 or 1024.76?

Comment: it rounds up to the no. of decimal places specified. Check here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

Answer (score 1):

Use **replace** function.  Whether the field is integer or varchar, it will work.

```
select replace(Fixes.GBPam,',','.');
```